# Return/consume dynamic anonymous type across assembly boundaries

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, anonymous-types

The code below works great. If the `Get` and `Use` methods are in different assemblies, the code fails with a RuntimeBinderException. This is because the .Net runtime system only guarantees commonality of anonymous types (`<string, int>` in this case) within assemblies.

Is there any way to fool the runtime system to overcome this? I can inspect the object in the debugger on the `Use` side, and the debugger can see the relevant properties.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UsePerson();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void UsePerson()
    {
        var person = GetPerson();

        Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
    }

    public static dynamic GetPerson()
    {
        return new { Name = "Foo", Age = 30 };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use an [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) instead of an anonymous type.  This should allow you to cross assembly boundaries safely:

```
public static dynamic GetPerson()
{
    dynamic person = new ExpandoObject();
    person.Name = "Foo";
    person.Age = 30;

    return person;
}
```

In general, anonymous types should really only be used within the same method in which they are generated.  Returning an anonymous type from a method is, in general, going to cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: Best answer because of ExpandoObject which solves the cross assembly limit.

Answer (score 8):

The cause of the problem is that anonymous types are internal to assemblies. That's why the Dynamic Language Runtime don't allow you to access properties from another assembly.

One solution is explained in this [post](http://www.heartysoft.com/ashic/blog/2010/5/anonymous-types-c-sharp-4-dynamic). You can put an custom attribute in the assembly that defines the anonymous type allowing the other assembly to access its internals.

Another solution is returning an object of a public class (with public properties). That will, of course, kill the advantages of the anonymous type.

A third solution would be using an [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) as suggested by **Reed Copsey**.

If you still want to use the anonymous type, you could write a dynamic class that "decorates" any anonymous type and exposes its members. Such a class would have to implement the [IDynamicMetaObjectProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.idynamicmetaobjectprovider.aspx) interface and access the decorated object via reflection. Possibly, this stuff was already implemented by someone out there.

Comment: Solution "1" in the above post is actually pretty interesting.  Basically [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("SomeOtherAssembly")] in your assemblyinfo.cs works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Another good solution might be to use tuples, which were introduced in .Net 4: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here's a poor man's workaround; Newtonsoft.Json to the rescue, as serialization roundtrip generates dynamic type instances visible to your/working assembly.

```
public static class TypeExt
{
  // roundtrip json serialization to enable access to dynamic members and properties originating from another assembly
  public static T JClone<T>( this T source ) { return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>( JsonConvert.SerializeObject( source ) ); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

impromptu-interface

http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/

Will let you use the the anonymous type instance across boundaries but you have to declare an interface that matches it's signature or at least what you want accessible from it's signature.