# Short way to achieve dynamic objects from LINQ to XML select query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml, initialization, expandoobject

Is there an initialization syntax to the `ExpandoObject` that I can use to my advantage in a  LINQ to XML query for brevity purposes?

*Note: The results of the query are intended to be passed outside the scope of the current assembly so anonymous types are out of the question ([see why here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993200/return-consume-dynamic-anonymous-type-across-assembly-boundaries)).*

I'm trying to use brief syntax like the following to create dynamic/expando objects:

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> ParseUserXml(string strXmlUser) {

var qClients =
    from client in xdoc.Root.Element(XKey.clients).Elements(XKey.client)
    // client object

    // I cannot get ExpandoObject to initialize inline 
    select new ExpandoObject() {     // try initialization syntax, COMPILE ERR
        OnlineDetails = new
        {
            Password = client.Element(XKey.onlineDetails).
                Element(XKey.password).Value,
            Roles = client.Element(XKey.onlineDetails).
                Element(XKey.roles).Elements(XKey.roleId).
                Select(xroleid => xroleid.Value)
            // More online detail fields TBD
        },

        // etc ....

        // YIELD DYNAMIC OBJECTS BACK THROUGH IEnumerable<dynamic>...
        foreach (var client in qClients)
        {
            yield return client;
        }
```

More involved solutions to make this code work might be:

- create concrete class and initialize it instead (but I don't want to create a bunch of those).
- use anonymous type and copy its members to a dynamic object (somewhat redundant) and return the dynamic objects

**Is there an equally short syntax to achieve what I intend to do by the erroneous code in question, or will I have to expand the code base in some manner to get the desired result?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using one of [Jon Skeet's code answers from a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161221/efficiency-of-creating-delegate-instance-inline-of-linq-query/5161310#5161310). Code sample copied here for posterity. It uses the raw classes rather than query syntax.

```
// Code answer by Jon Skeet.
var qClients = xdoc.Root
       .Element(XKey.clients)
       .Elements(XKey.client)
       .Select(client => {
           dynamic o = new ExpandoObject();
           o.OnlineDetails = new ExpandoObject();
           o.OnlineDetails.Password = client.Element(XKey.onlineDetails)
                                            .Element(XKey.password).Value;
           o.OnlineDetails.Roles = client.Element(XKey.onlineDetails)
                                         .Element(XKey.roles)
                                         .Elements(XKey.roleId)
                                         .Select(xroleid => xroleid.Value);
           return o; 
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think you'll be able to do this. What you can do is create a helper method and call it.

```
var qClients =
    from client in xdoc.Root.Element(XKey.clients).Elements(XKey.client)
    // client object
    select ClientXmlToExpandoObject(client);
```

The helper might look something like

```
public dynamic ClientXmlToExpandoObject(System.Xml.Linq.XElement client)
{
    dynamic result = new ExpandoObject();
    result.OnlineDetails = new
        {
            Password = client.Element(XKey.onlineDetails).
                Element(XKey.password).Value,
            Roles = client.Element(XKey.onlineDetails).
                Element(XKey.roles).Elements(XKey.roleId).
                Select(xroleid => xroleid.Value)
            // More online detail fields TBD
        };
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is cool solution, DynamicXml: http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/kevin-hazzard/fluent-xml-parsing-using-cs-dynamic-type-part-1