# List<T> LINQ Projection to Anonymous or Dynamic type

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I'm trying to convert a `List<Topic>` to an anonymous or dynamic type via linq projection... I'm am using the following code, but it doesn't seem to work properly. It returns the dynamic type  without error, however, if I try to enumerate the children field (`list<object/topic>`) then it says

> Results View = The type `'<>f__AnonymousType6<id,title,children>'` exists in both 'MyWebCore.dll' and 'MvcExtensions.dll'

Strange.

Here is the code I am using:

```
protected dynamic FlattenTopics()
{
    Func<List<Topic>, object> _Flatten = null; // satisfy recursion re-use
    _Flatten = (topList) =>
    {
        if (topList == null) return null;

        var projection = from tops in topList
                         select new
                         {
                             id = tops.Id,
                             title = tops.Name,
                             children = _Flatten(childs.Children.ToList<Topic>())
                         };
        dynamic transformed = projection;
        return transformed;
    };

    var topics = from tops in Repository.Query<Topic>().ToList()
                 select new
                 {
                     id = tops.Id,
                     title = tops.Name,
                     children = _Flatten(tops.Children.ToList<Topic>())
                 };

    return topics;
}
```

All i'm doing is flattening a list of self containing objects - basically it's a list of POCOs that will be stuffed into a tree view (jstree).

The Topic class is defined as:

```
public class Topic
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Topic> Children {get;set;}
}
```

And here is an example of what the first member of the returned dynamic object looks like:

```
[0] = { 
    id = {566697be-b336-42bc-9549-9feb0022f348},
    title = "AUTO", 
    children = {System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManyIterator
          <MyWeb.Models.Topic,
           MyWeb.Models.Topic,
           <>f__AnonymousType6<System.Guid,string,object>
          >} 
 }
```

Comment: Are you calling FlattenTopics from another assembly? Anonymous types cannot be used across assemblies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993200/return-consume-dynamic-anonymous-type-across-assembly-boundaries

Comment: LINQ results don't work well out of scope, due to the anonymous types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336312.aspx

Comment: @Igor - no - from an Action method within my MVC controller...

Comment: @Ryan - even before the topics var is returned to the calling Action method it gives the same issue explained in above post.  The Children child object is only getting populated down to about one or two levels.

Comment: @bbqchickenrobot The `Action` that you call recursively is a new scope on each recursion.

Comment: @Ryan - works when I select into a  new object ... don't think that's it... will post how I was able to get it to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the proper way - have to load into the a DTO / POCO and return that:

```
_Flatten = (topList) =>
        {
            if (topList == null) return null;

            var projection = from tops in topList
                             //from childs in tops.Children
                             select new JsTreeJsonNode
                             {
                                 //id = tops.Id.ToString(),
                                 data = tops.Name,
                                 attr = setAttributes(tops.Id.ToString(), tops.URI),
                                 state = "closed",
                                 children = _Flatten(tops.Children)
                             };


            return projection.ToList();
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have the same LINQ code twice? After you define your _Flatten func, you can just call it immediately - `var topics = _Flatten(Repository.Query<Topic>().ToList()`.

It looks like you're creating two identical anonymous types, one inside the _Flatten func and one outside it. I would think the compiler is smart enough to handle that, but try changing your call to explicitly use _Flatten, see if it solves the problem.