# Get fields from anonymous type

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

I have this class:

```
public class allFields
{
    public string EAN { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string qty { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}
```

And a function that return an anonymous type:

```
public IEnumerable<object> stockEtatQty()
{   
    List<allFields> afList = new List<allFields>();

    var query = from x in ctx.book
                where x.qty > 0
                select x;
    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        allFields af = new allFields();
        af.EAN = item.EAN;
        af.title = item.Titre;
        af.qty = ""+item.Quantite;
        afList.Add(af);
    }
    var q = from x in afList
            select new { EAN=x.EAN, Title=x.title, Quantity=x.qty };

    return q; //q is a IEnumerable<'a> where a is new {string EAN, string Title, string Quantity}
}
```

In my WinForm a use this function as below:

```
private void QuantityToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServiceStock sstock = new ServiceStock();
    var q = sstock.stockEtatQty().ToList();// q is a list<object>
    string str = "";
    foreach (var item in q)
    {
        str += item + Environment.NewLine;
    }
    MessageBox.Show(str);
}
```

The result is:

```
{ EAN = 1, Title = CSharp Security, Quantity = 970 }
{ EAN = 2, Title = MISC, Quantity = 100 }
...
```

**What I want?** 
I want not like the result above, but separate each field apart of the `item` in the loop `foreach`, e.g get `item.EAN`, `item.Title` and `item.Quantity`.

If there is no solution for my problem I would like to know an alternative,
Thanks for help.

Comment: I had difficulty getting past `public class allFields`. Please read up on choosing good class names.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is to create a custom type (let's call it `BookInfo`) and return a `IEnumerable<BookInfo>` instead of a `IEnumerable<object>` (and maybe override `ToString` if you want to put the formatting into this class itself).

Then you can easily format the output.

```
public class BookInfo
{
    public string EAN {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public int Quantity {get;set;}
}

public IEnumerable<BookInfo> stockEtatQty()
{   
    ...

    var q = from x in afList
            select new BookInfo { EAN=x.EAN, Title=x.title, Quantity=x.qty };

    return q;
}

private void QuantityToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServiceStock sstock = new ServiceStock();
    var q = sstock.stockEtatQty();

    var message = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
                              q.Select(item => String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", item.EAN, item.Title, item.Quantity)));
    MessageBox.Show(message);
}
```

Comment: Actually I have more than 5 functions that do same as `stockEtatQty` but they return different results, e.g I have another function `stockEtatPrice` that return EAN, Title and Price (instead of Quantity), and another function `stockEtatDate` that return date (instead of Quantity or Price)

Comment: @user3757742 Are you always just going to convert the data into a string (in which case, the methods can all just return the formatted string) or do they sometimes do other things with the data?  Keep in mind that if you have a number of similar methods that are all returning similar but different things then having different types is *all the more important*.  It ensures that you have the compiler there to verify that you do everything correctly, instead of having an error prone solution that the compiler cannot validate.

Answer (score 1):

Since the static type information about the object of anonymous type is lost by the time that you exit `stockEtatQty()` method, you could cast the object to `dynamic` and access fields like this:

```
str = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, q.Cast<dynamic>().Select(item => 
    string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", item.EAN, item.Title, item.Quantity)
));
```

The cast to `dynamic` tells the compiler that `EAN`, `Title`, and `Quantity` need to be resolved at runtime.

Note that I also replaced the `foreach` loop with a call to `string.Join` to improve performance: repeated string concatenation creates unnecessary partial string objects, which `string.Join` avoids. Another solution would be to use `StringBuider` instead of string concatenation `+=`.

> `stockEtatQty` is in a project (Service) and `QuantityToolStripMenuItem_Click` is in another project (View)

Unfortunately, this means that you would not be able to use anonymous types: anonymous types are generated with internal visibility, limiting their use to the assembly in which they are produced. You can use a work-around based on `ExpandoObject` described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2993247/335858):

```
var q = afList.Select(x => {
    dynamic res = new ExpandoObject();
    res.EAN=x.EAN;
    res.Title=x.title;
    res.Quantity=x.qty;
    return res;
});
```

Comment: I try your solution but I have this error at the build-time: _'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions.Cast<TResult>(System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context_

Comment: @user3757742 Please see the fix - my code was missing a pair of parentheses.

Comment: Now I have this error: 'object' doesn't contain a definition for 'EAN'

Comment: @user3757742 I just ran this locally, and obtained precisely the result that I expected to get. By any chance, is `stockEtatQty()` a member of a class from a different project than `QuantityToolStripMenuItem_Click`? The reason I am asking is that anonymous classes are internal.

Comment: yes, `stockEtatQty()` is in a project (Service) and `QuantityToolStripMenuItem_Click` is in another project (View) @dasblinkenlight

Answer (score 0):

You can use collection of dynamic objects instead of simple objects as return type of your method:

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> stockEtatQty()
```

Then you will not have IntelliSense but at runtime properties will be found:

```
foreach (var item in sstock.stockEtatQty())    
    str += String.Format("{0}", item.EAN) + Environment.NewLine;
```

But I suggest you to create custom class with EAN, Title and Quantity properties. Or just use your `allFields` instead of anonymous objects.

---

Consider also to use StringBuilder for string creation to avoid creating lot of in-memory strings:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var item in sstock.stockEtatQty())
   builder.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", item.EAN, Environment.NewLine);

MessageBox.Show(builder.ToString());
```

Comment: I try your solution but I have this error: 'object' doesn't contain a definition for 'EAN'

Comment: @user3757742 you should use exactly same name as property of anonymous object. Also I think you haven't modified return type of your method

Comment: I modified the return type from _IEnumerable<object>_ to _IEnumerable<dynamic>_ and I put the same name as property of anonymous object but still give me the same error

Comment: @user3757742 sorry, but it should not. If you have done everything correctly, you should get property value (which will be evaluated at runtime)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class that represents the new object structure and return that.

```
var q = from x in afList
        select new SmallerType { EAN=x.EAN, Title=x.title, Quantity=x.qty };
```

WinForm Function

```
foreach (SmallerType item in q)
{
  //
}
```