# Lambda query does not working with Moq data for `Task<IEnumerable<dynamic>>` return type method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dynamic, mocking, moq

This query does not working while giving dummy data via Moq Setup.

```
colorsList.Select(cl => (string)cl.MainTypeCode).Where(mt => mt != null).Distinct().ToList()
```

Passing data by Using Moq:

```
 mockColorsRepository.Setup(rep => rep.GetColorsList()).Returns(Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<dynamic>>
                (new[] { new { DoorCode = "001", MainTypeCode = "1" }, new { DoorCode = "002", MainTypeCode = "2" } }));
```

Where `GetColorsList()` has an async method and dynamic return type

```
Task<IEnumerable<dynamic>> GetColorsList();
```

[image]

Passing data by hardcoding:

But it is working while I am hardcoding same way of data without using Moq, like

```
 var colorsList = Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<dynamic>>(new[] { new { DoorCode = "001", MainTypeCode = "1" },
                    new { DoorCode = "002", MainTypeCode = "2" } }).Result;
```

[image]

**The problem is**: you can see the data in both way while of debugging, But the Lambda query does not working while passing Mock data via Moq Setup.

> **Note** Does not working means it's throwing an  *`Object` does not contains a definition for `maintypecode`* error.

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `dynamic` at all here?

Comment: What happens if you try to use something like this? `carlist.Select(cl => (string)((dynamic)cl).MainTypeCode).Where(...` Also, I'd tear that entire class apart and leave the `dynamic` aside, if I were you

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Will try and let you know

Comment: What is the type of ```cl``` the breaking example and what properties does it have?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto tried. The same error is throwing

Comment: @PiotrJustyna Are ypu seeing my question? you can see there that is Enumerable of dynamic data  which means anonymous property

Comment: @RameshRajendran Dynamic does not mean anonymous. When you preview the ```cl```'s type in the debugger, what do you see?

Comment: You are not getting a list of dynamic objects, you are getting a list of `AnonymousType<..>`; I think anonymous types are internal by default hence you aren't able to access the properties from another library, namely your test project.

Comment: @DaveParsons **I think anonymous types are internal by default hence you aren't able to access the properties from another library, namely your test project.** So what we will do in this case of situation?

Comment: @RameshRajendran Dude, check the type and you'll be able to reason what to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @DaveParsons to gave me a key idea.

> I think anonymous types are internal by default hence you aren't able to access the properties from another library, namely your test project

I got it from this discussion : [Return/consume dynamic anonymous type across assembly boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993200/return-consume-dynamic-anonymous-type-across-assembly-boundaries)

So I am go to use`ExpandoObject`  for mocking data

```
  public static IEnumerable<dynamic> GetValues()
        {
            List<ExpandoObject> expando = new List<ExpandoObject>();

            dynamic expandoObject = new ExpandoObject();
            expandoObject.DoorCode = "123";
            expandoObject.MainTypeCode = "123";
            expando.Add(expandoObject);

            dynamic expandoObject1 = new ExpandoObject();
            expandoObject1.DoorCode = "321";
            expandoObject1.MainTypeCode = "321";
            expando.Add(expandoObject1);

            return expando;
        }
```

I am passing that mock data to the return method of `Moq setup` like

```
 mockColorsRepository.Setup(rep => rep.GetColorsList()).Returns(Task.FromResult(GetValues()));
```

Everything is working now.

Answer (score 2):

Your mock is returning an `IEnumerable<f__AnonymousType0<string,string>>` which is generated by the compiler as an **`internal`** class and so you don't have access to the properties from your test library.

Ideally you would be able to rewrite so as to replace your use of `dynamic` with a class that you define and have control over (and can therefore access appropriately).

Another option would be to use reflection to get the values from the object something along the lines of `cl.GetType().GetProperty("MainTypeCode").GetValue(cl)` this is, in my opinion, a bit of a hacky solution but it's an option nonetheless.